# Sharepoint : where is user configuration for webparts?

Tags: web-part, rest, csom, configuration

I'm googling and googling again to find where sharepoint store the settings for webparts.
Especially where it stores the user settings for one webpart and where it stores the disposition/order of webpart in a page.
I found nothing.

Can you point me in the right direction ?

Can this be altered using csom or rest ?

EDIT: I'm not looking how to write a webpart and expose its properties. I want to know where sharepoint stores values of those properties for user X or Y.

Comment: they are webpart properties and are stored in property

Comment: This is a bit vague. I want to know where those properties are stored. A (hidden) list ? xml files on server ? blob in database ?

Comment: The webpart propertes, leave in somewhere, this is no joke. I assume that these properties are stored in the database, along with the information on the page where the webpart is. If you open the page with SharePoint Designer, you will see the properties of the webpart within the tag <webpart:. So the properties are saved as plain text into the page, but the page is stored in somewhere in the content database of the site, and this tag is rendered by .NET so the properties are never public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Part properties information stores in a content database under "AllWebParts" table.

There are all user properties and personal properties which stores in 2 different columns

- tp_AllUserProperties - properties for all users
- tp_PerUserProperties - Properties per user

Answer (score 0):

As commented the settings are stored in the property of the webpart,
And it totally depends on what the property type example whether it is of type string,enum,float etc.

[For more details you check for create custom webpart properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174(v=office.11).aspx)